# Centre align div that has float: left

Tags: html, css, css-float, background-image

I have 3 images that are all in the same line and float left but i would also like to centre them. I have tried using `margin: 0px auto;` but it doesn't seem to do anything. Any suggestions?

CSS:

```
#boxes .box {
    width:370px;
    height:241px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-image:url(../imgs/box_front.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-color: #FFF;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your selector, I can make out that the boxes which are floated to the left are nested inside element having an id of `#boxes`, so if you can, assign some fixed width to `#boxes` and than use `margin: auto;`

```
#boxes {
   width: 800px; /* You need to set this */
   margin: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FF5cy/)

Comment: @iNeed_anAnswer You welcome, I provided the demo as well, you can resize the fiddle frame to see the expected result, also don't forget to clear floats :)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to center floated items. One of the things you can do - is make the items `inline-block` and set the `text-align: center` property to their parent. Online example: http://jsfiddle.net/8HPWU/

Answer (score 0):

You should align to center to your parent div that is `#boxes` not to your image. Try this:

```
#boxes{
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS

```
#boxes .box {
    width:370px;
    height:241px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-image:url(../imgs/box_front.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    background-color: #FFF;

}
```